# Primefaces datatable rows per page template dropdown focus should be on the top pagination

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have a p:datatable with paginatorPosition="both" and rowsPerPageTemplate="15, 25, 50, 75". On loading the focus should come on the top dropdown. But the focus is coming on the bottom dropdown.

```
<p:dataTable id="resultsTable_#{cc.attrs.lovId}" var="lov" paginator="true" rows="15" value="#{cc.attrs.dataModel}" rowsPerPageTemplate="15, 25, 50, 75"
                     rowKey="#{cc.attrs.rowKey}" selectionMode="single" pageLinks="5" paginatorPosition="both" rowIndexVar="rowIndexVar"
                     paginatorTemplate="Page {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" styleClass="LOVTable"
                     selection="#{lovPreferences.selectedObj}"
                     widgetVar="lovTable_#{cc.attrs.lovId}"
                     filteredValue = "#{lovPreferences.filteredResults}"
                     emptyMessage="Data is loading please wait..."
                     lazy = "#{cc.attrs.lazyLoadIndicator}"
                     filterDelay="1000"
                >
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gQxz.jpg

Comment: Sorry, but I'm curious about why do you need this?

Comment: when the focus is at the bottom, the dropdown options are not completely visible.

Comment: @santosh, if my answer resolved your problem, don't forget to [accept it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function:

```
...
<h:body onload='ExecuteFunction()' >
    <script>
    function ExecuteFunction() {
        jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
            jQuery("yourFormID:yourDatatableID:yourPaginatorID)".addClass('ui-state-hover ui-state-focus'));
        });
    }
    </script>
...
```

Regards,